# Using Anaconda Python in cmd

Tags: python, cmd

I have installed anaconda navigator then python 3.7 to practice basic codes using Python IDLE.

In this case, when I try to use Python from CMD, python 3.7 was used. If I want to use Anaconda python in CMD, what should I do ?

Do I need to delete Python 3.7 from Path Variable? Is it possible to leave Path Variable and just use Anaconda Python in CMD?

Thanks

Comment: Anaconda have sepatae cmd called `Anaconda Prompt`. Search for `Anaconda Prompt` in your machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda has Anaconda Prompt. You can use python command to work on python there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply install python and open terminal & simply you can run python command to practise. Incase of Anaconda It has own prompt.